# какие варианты запуска скриптов по расписанию?

Tags: linux, bash

У меня есть несколько bash-скриптов. Какие варианты их запуска по расписанию, помимо крона, есть в Linux системах? Есть ли какие-то преимущества у них над кроном?

Comment: А чем вам крон не угодил?

Comment: в образовательных целях. Есть же ещё systemd, хотелось бы про него тоже мнение услышать. А так cron не учитывает нагрузку на систему, например.

Comment: `systemd` предоставляет фактически свою реализацию `cron`. Помимо этого есть планировщик `atd`.

Comment: Есть ещё *anacron*.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант - написать самому. Например, в Python есть модуль [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/). Сразу и пример попробуйте:

```py
$ pip install schedule

$ echo 'echo "pid $$ executed at $(date +%H:%M:%S)"'>my.sh

$ python3 <<EOF
import schedule
import time
import subprocess 

def job():
     sp = subprocess.run(['bash', 'my.sh'])

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.at("08:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1*10)
EOF
pid 2964 executed at 07:10:53
pid 2966 executed at 07:11:53
```